# High power amps

Tags: amperage

Can anyone help me with amplifying a 5V 200 MHz sine wave for a project related to Volumetric Electromagnetic Phase-Shift Spectroscopy?

I require a sine wave through a coil which has 200 MHz and can provide 10 mA current.
But I am stuck how to amplify such a signal either I am lacking knowledge or making some mistake.
The thing is what kind of amp should I use as i don't really know which opamp IC to use so can anyone help me with this as I want to design my own circuit for it.

Need to generate a 200Mhz signal of 2V to supply 10mA and pass it through an amp so that i could pass it through a coli and then in an another coil i need to see the phase change due to mutual inductance.

Comment: You need to amplify it, Okay. From what to what?

Comment: What voltage is required across the coil? and what is the coil inductance?

Comment: There is an inconsistency in your post. Do you need the sine wave to  be  2V (peak? or rms?) across the inductor? Or do you need the sine wave to be 10mA (peak? or RMS?) through the inductor? You cannot have both at the same time unless the coils is a very specific inductance.

Comment: To the OP: You should contact the author indicated by pjc50's answer. Namely, Casar Gonzalez, at "cgonzalezd@ipn.mx" and then directly ask for help. Be considerate and express your reasons, clearly. I think you will get the help you want. (The output you are talking about will generate several milliamps current in just 1 pF load. So *everything* matters in this. This includes connector details, etc. This is an area where you want access to the very best and most knowledable people.)

Comment: Thank you for your help, i know there are many inconsistencies in my post i am in my learning phase but still thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Interesting technology there, this VEPSS stuff.](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0063223)

Fortunately that article gives a comprehensive description of their setup, *including part numbers*.

> The digital synthesizer is a signal generator AD9958 (Analog Device Inc. Norwood, MA, USA). It supplies a sinusoidal current, Icos(ωt), of approximately 10 mA rms in the frequency range of 1–200 MHz. The current is supplied at 200 pre-programmed equally spaced frequencies, under PC control. The transceiver consists of two concentric coils with radii of R1 = 3.2 cm and R2 = 11 cm, separated by a distance of 10 cm. Both coils were built from ten turns of magnet wire AWG22 rolled on an ergonomic plastic harness specifically designed for an adult human head (Figure 2). The coil inductances, calculated from Faraday’s law, are approximately 67.4 and 796.4 µH for the inductor and sensor coils, respectively. The estimated mutual inductance coefficient is approximately M = 72.8 µH. To avoid inductive pickup the leads of the coils are twisted. A commercial device, AD8302 (Analog Devices Inc. Norwood, MA, USA) was used for phase detection. The AD8302 is a fully integrated RF IC for measuring differences in phase between two signals with a resolution of 10 mV/degree. The signals from the inductor and sensor coils are connected through a 5X preamplifier SR445 (Standford Research System Inc. Sunnyvale, CA, USA) to the digital synthesizer and phase detector module...

It seems like their choice of DAC can just output 10ma directly. Or at least that's the peak indicated in the datasheet. It's not an especially high power application.